# Difference between PC SAS and Server SAS

Tags: java, sas

Actually my project is integrated with Java. From Java SAS code is calling by using  drop downs. Currently, we are using server SAS. Now my client wants to move to PC SAS instead of the server SAS. What difference does it make in my application?

Comment: What operating system are you currently running "Server SAS" on?

Comment: And what version of SAS?

Answer (score 9):

PC SAS - It is a single machine installation of SAS software. It generally consists of SAS Foundation tools such as Base SAS, SAS/STAT & SAS/GRAPH software components (product - SAS Analytics Pro). It provides the benefits of data integration, data manipulation, data analysis and data presentation (reporting and visualization) at small scale. It is used within smaller teams within departments focusing on particular business process or part of business process.

Server SAS - It is an enterprisewide version of SAS software. It is installed on multiple machines (two or more) based on customer requirements. It can be used by multiple users at the same time. It requires higher hardware configuration than PC SAS. It contains four tiers - Web Tier (mainly presentation layer), middle tier(where java applications execute), server tier and data tier (enterprise data sources). It is highly customizable in terms of number of add-on components required by customer based on their requirements.

Client tools for development - SAS DI Studio (ETL development), SAS Infomap Studio (to create business metadata layer for reporting), SAS WRS (SAS report authoring tool), SAS OLAP Cube Studio (SAS cube development and maintenance tool)

End user tool - SAS Information Delivery Portal (SAS Portal for users to view reports)

Answer (score 4):

Well, the REALLY STRONG difference is: horsepower.

Usually the "Server SAS" comes in a huge server, so its constraints are smaller (think fast hard drives, lots of RAM, several processors...). I am talking something like 300GB of RAM, not to mention the terabytes of hard drive space available.

The "Computer SAS" won't have any of that. So, there.

I do not know if there are differences about the language used in both. I really don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

In broad terms, the differences come down to Horsepower (as just_testing commented on) vs. Cost.

SAS's server products are very powerful.  I have been able to use SAS's BI and Grid products running about 25 TB a day in an enterprise application without much of an issue.  PC licenses do a good for small custom jobs/business intelligence applications.

In terms of cost, SAS licenses its software based on the processor speed.  In cases, where you are operating a Larger server application, this can reach into the six figures pretty easily.  A PC SAS license is closer to a couple thousand.  This licensing structure will probably change as more users adopt Hadoop platforms.  ****NOTE: contact your SAS Sales professional for specific pricing... this is based on my own personal experience. ****

Answer (score 1):

The most important difference in terms of compatibility are to note if there are any **shell** commands used in the existing programs (copying files, executing shell scripts, using the "x" command in SAS, typically). Otherwise look out for absolute file paths that refer to local files saved on the server, otherwise it's mainly a performance difference. However there are some advantages that most people overlook with PC SAS... for instance the ability to use DDE which allows you to control other Windows programs is completely non-existent on non-windows servers.

Also, it's usually wrong to assume you can't process large amounts of data with PC SAS, you just have to be a little more disciplined about it by using the SQL pass-through method for your proc sql and having the database do the heavy lifting for you. With PC SAS you will want to work mainly with data that has already been reduced/summarized a bit by the database when the data gets big.

Answer (score 0):

suppose we take sas 9.2 .

Requirments for sas9.2 is minimum 2 GB RAM and  some processor. this tool is running on less PC requirments

In my orgonization 10 pcs are there . so 10 pcs require a small RAM like 2 GB

We take SASBI package . these tools requirments are very high .

Orgonization unable to invest that huge amount of money for pcs.

so  install SASBI on SERVER and Install client editons on pcs then give connection from pc to server for acessing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is whether SAS code hardcode the directories or libname explicitly.
That requires changes to SAS code.
But if your JAVA code also hardcode about where to submit the SAS code. that is the thing  you should address from yourside.